# Searching in datatable using textbox with multiple values

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have tried searching for single value and i am able to do  that. But i am not able to search in datatable with multiple values. Please let me know how to search in datatable with multiple values.

I am using jquery 1.9 and datatable 1.9

Example:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < finalSplittedTxt.length; j++) {
            if ((aData[i]).toLowerCase().indexOf(finalSplittedTxt[j].toLowerCase()) >= 0‌​) {
                 return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: it would be great if anyone can help me ASAP

Comment: What kind of database? Also, show us your code of what works and what doesn't, please.

Comment: my data is static. am not fetching from database.

Comment: My bad, misread that tag. So the question is still, what's your code look like?

Comment: finalSplittedTxt is array of values which i need to search

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "multiple values". Datatables 1.9 lets you pass in a Regular Expression into the filter function. At that point you can pretty much do any kind of filtering you want. See fnFilter params here http://legacy.datatables.net/api